# How to implement username availability using JSP

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

In my application I have a username with a textbox, a checkbutton and a password. After entering the username into the textbox, if I click on check button it should search in the MySQL database for the username, if it is available it should display the message if not an other message should be displayed.

[image]

How do I do that with JSP?
i tried the follwing code:

```
    <form  method="post" name="frm_addUser" action="./adduserserver.jsp"><br><br>
<table width="500px;" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#f8f8ff" bordercolor="#333366" align="center">


<tr>
<td bordercolor="Gainsboro"><font size="4">User ID</font></td>
<td bordercolor="Gainsboro"><input name="userid" style="WIDTH: 200px"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td bordercolor="Gainsboro"><font size="4">&nbsp;</font></td>

<!--<td><input value="Check availability" onclick="" class="btn_checkavail" type="button"></td></tr>-->
</td>
<td>
<input type="submit" value="check" name="check" 
onclick="" /></td></tr>     
<tr>
<td bordercolor="Gainsboro"><font size="4">Pass Word </font></td>
<td bordercolor="Gainsboro"><input name="password" type="password" style="WIDTH: 200px"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td bordercolor="Gainsboro"><font size="4">Confirm Password </font></td>
<td bordercolor="Gainsboro"><input name="confirmpassword" type="password" style="WIDTH: 200px"></td></tr>
<tr>
<%
try{
String username=request.getParameter("username");

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","sumith");
    st=con.createStatement();

    sqlQuery="select distinct username from usernameexist where username='"+username+"'";
    rs=st.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
int count=0;
while(rs.next())
{
count++;
}
if(count>0)
{
            out.println("<html>");
                        out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>MeterDetailsPage</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
                        out.println("<table align='center' color='red'>");
                        out.println("<tr color='red'>");
                        out.println("<td ><font size=4 color=red >username  Already Exist</font></td>");
                        out.println("</tr>");
                        out.println("</table>");
                        out.println("</body>");
                        out.println("</html>");
}

else
{

if(username!=null )

{

if(!username.equals(""))

{

            //st.executeUpdate("insert into usernameexist(username) values('"+username+"')");
            out.println("<html>");
                        out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>username</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
                        out.println("<table align='center'>");
                        out.println("<tr>");
                        out.println("<td ><font size=4  color=green><b>available </b></font></td>");
            out.println("</table>");
                        out.println("</body>");
                        out.println("</html>");
}
}
}
st.close();
con.close();
}
catch(Exception e){}
%>



</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, what way you want to walk? Multiple options. Make column unique in your database, or use 2 queries. 1 to look for duplicate, other to insert if possible. If I have not understand your question, plz explain your problem better and tell us what you have tried.

Comment: thanks for your reply.actually my problem is i have username with textbox if i enter the username ,after clicking on button it should check weather it is exist or not.if exist it should display username is exist or if not i will proceed further .

Comment: i have edited my post also.

Comment: You can use ajax for this. On button click, call a function that makes an ajax call to some jsp which checks if username is available or not

Comment: thank you sree can i write the code using jsp?if yes i have posted my jsp code please varify and help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Try This it will work,

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Index Page</title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/app-ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

        Enter Your Name: <input type="text" id="name" /><br>
        Enter our user name :<input type="text" id="userName"><br>
        Enter your Password :<input type="password" id="password"><br>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="ajaxCall();">        
    <br>

    <strong> Response</strong>:
    <div id="ajaxGetUserServletResponse"></div><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Ajax file

```
function ajaxCall(){
    var name = jQuery("#name").val(); 
    var userName = jQuery("#userName").val();
    var password= jQuery("#password").val();
    alert(name);
    alert(userName);
    alert(password);

    jQuery.ajax({
        url : "GetUserServlet", 
        method: "GET", 
        type : "JSON", 
        data : "name="+name+"&userName="+userName+"&password="+password,// query parameters 1st 
        success : function(response){
            $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(response);

        }
    });


}
```

Servlet

```
import java.io.IOException;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.management.relation.RelationSupportMBean;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class GetUserServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        userBean ub = new userBean();
        String name = request.getParameter("name").trim();
        String userName = request.getParameter("userName").trim();
        String password = request.getParameter("password").trim();

        System.out.println("name catched "+name);
        System.out.println("username catched"+userName);
        System.out.println("Password catched"+password);


        ArrayList<userBean> list = new ArrayList<userBean>();
         ub=new userBean();
         ub.setName(name);
         ub.setUserName(userName);
         ub.setPassword(password);
         list.add(ub);  

         response.setContentType("text/plain");
         response.getWriter().print(list);             
    }

}
```

Pojo Class

```
public class userBean 
{
    private String name;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

My scenario was little bit different you can alter the code in index.jsp and add the call on button "Check Availability" and bring the response from servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Your should do below :

1. Make sure that your jsp is passing all fields including checked field to servlet. You can do form post which has all attributes.
2. Your servlet should read all parameters and if check-box is checked then you put appropriate logic in servlet (like querying your MySQL db)
3. Return proper response from your servlet so that jsp can show appropriate message. You can keep messages in your jsp/js and based on flag you can show appropriate message to user.

Answer (score 0):

check your table name in query

```
select distinct username from usernameexist where username='"+username+"'";
```

make sure your table is usernameexist

and

```
String username=request.getParameter("username");
```

here parameter is userid not username

so use

```
String username=request.getParameter("userid");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use as follows.. attach jquery file in source code

```
 <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js">
```

IN Form

```
 <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" onBlur="checkId(this.value)">
 <span id="status"></span>

 <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkId(member_id)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "processAjax.jsp", /* The request will be processed in this file.. */
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $("#divIdStatus").html("geting name...");
                },
                data: "member_id=" + member_id ,
                success: function(msg) {
                    $("#divIdStatus").html(msg);
                }
            });
        }
```

IN processAjax.js

```
 String member_id = (request.getParameter("member_id")).trim();
        if (member_id.equals("")) {
            out.print("! This is Required");
        } else {


            ResultSet result = // check in database if any record with this user name;

            if (result.next()) {
                out.print("! Not Available");
            } else {
                out.print("OK..");
            }
        }
```

Comment: this will call this function onBlur you can call on button click also